# create multiple drop down dynamically with different id using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

I have a select drop down with some id name. I want to make a clone of it with different Id name dynamically using javascript. here is my code.

```
<td>
            <div style="float: left;">
                <g:select name="degree.id" from="${DomainName.list()}" optionKey="id"
                          optionValue="title" noSelection="['': '']" id="degree"
                          value="${cvEducationDetailCO?.degree?.id}" onchange="changeGradeSelectData(this.value)"/>
            </div>

        </td>
<a href="javascript:void (0);" onclick="addAnotherSelectBox();">Add Another Select Box </a>
```

what will be jquery for this?

I have a table in which there are a tr and a td. in that td there is a select box. I need to make a clone of select box and put it into new row.user can generate many select box at his need. so I want that generate a dynamic tr and in which create clone of select box with new Id.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery you can say:

```
var newSelect = $("#degree").clone().prop("id", "newIdHere");
```

And then you can add it to your page with:

```
newSelect.appendTo("selector of parent element here");
// OR
$("selector of parent").append(newSelect);
// e.g., to add to same div as original:
$("#degree").parent().append(newSelect);
```

It would also be better not to include inline event attributes like your `onclick=...`, especially if you're already using jQuery:

```
<a href="#" id="addSelect">Add Another Select Box </a>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addSelect").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newSelect = $("#degree").clone().prop("id", "newIdHere");
        newSelect.wrap("<tr><td></td></tr>").closest("tr").appendTo("#idOfTableHere");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanx for your reply. I want to add it in tr or in a table. can I create table or tr dynamically also and want to put drop down in that table or tr. what will be code code for this.

Comment: Well which is it to be, a tr or a table? Please update your question to say clearly what you want to do, perhaps giving an example of what the html should look like both before _and_ after the new content is added dynamically. (I don't want to sit here guessing what you _might_ want and have you keep adding new requirements via comments.)

Comment: I have a table in which there are a tr and a td. in that td there is a  select box. I need to make a clone of select box and put it into new row.user can generate many select box at his need. so I want that generate a dynamic tr and in which create clone of select box with new Id.

Comment: So, again, edit your question to provide that information. Meanwhile I'll update my question with one way to do that.